# Can we get different answers using FTC1 and FTC2?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have just starting studying Calculus II after a very long break in college. In my class we just covered FTC1 and FTC2 in class and I was talked to evaluate two integrals using both of the ways.

I have gotten different answers using FTC1 and FTC2 and I was wondering if it is correct!

[image: Here is the problem!]

[image: My answers are here!]

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Anna! Yes, your answers should match. Is the error just up to a constant, or something more significant? Could we please see your two answers to verify?

Comment: @bounceback thank you so much! I have edited my question to add the pictures, I am rally sorry if the mistakes I made are way too bad (I am just trying to get back into studying maths!!)!

Comment: Is $F(x)=\displaystyle\int_1^x(t-t^3)\,\mathrm dt$? And are you supposed to find $F'(x)$? There's no question posed here.

Comment: Yes, @user170231, I am supposed to find F'(x)! I am sorry I didn't clarify earlier!

Comment: @AnnaM In the second part you just compute $F(x)$, so take its derivative. (Also on the first part, you had the right answer but then multiplied by $-1$ for some reason in the last step.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen oh yes, I see it!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your FTCII calculation is correct. You have used linearity of the integral, splitting it into two smaller integrals, which is a perfectly valid approach. I might approach the problem more directly, and simply write
$$
F(x) = \int_1^x t - t^3 \ dt = \left[\frac{1}{2}t^2 - \frac{1}{4}t^4 \right]_1^x = \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{- x^4+2x^2 - 1}{4} = -\frac{(x^2-1)^2}{4},
$$
matching your answer.
But as spaceisdarkgreen pointed out in the comments, if we then wish to compute the derivative, the chain rule gives
$$
F'(x) = -\frac{1}{4}(2x)(2)(x^2-1) = -x(x^2-1) = -x^3 + x,
$$
matching your FTCI answer (before the false manipulation in your last equality, I think you just forgot to include the $-$ sign). All good!